# Why the file-test operator does not work (Perl)?

Tags: perl, unix, access-rights

In "Programming Perl" `-w` file-test operator described as:

> –w File is writable by effective UID/GID.

I have two files:

```
-rwsrwxrwx 1 testuser testuser 226 Jul 20 20:31 script.pl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testuser testuser  34 Jul 14 17:24 file.txt
```

`suid` is set on `script.pl`, so when I run it as user caligula, effective UID/GID should be the  testuser's one. `script.pl` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
if (-w 'file.txt') {
    say "true";
}
else {
    say "false";
}
```

But when I run it `caligula@ubuntu-host:~$ ./script.pl` the output is always `false`. Why does that happen, may be I didn't understand the correct usage of that operator?

My appreciation.

Comment: FYI: Perl 5.16.0 is now available, though that may be old news to everyone but me since the most recent dates in the tar ball are 2012-05-20 so it was packaged about then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perl can be configured so that SUID scripts are ignored; it is the default, and likely how yours is set up.  You should print the real and effective UID and GID in the script.

You can validate this concretely with a modestly obscure Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -MConfig -e 'foreach $key (keys %Config) { print "$key = $Config{$key}\n"; }' |
> grep -i -e 'se*t*[ug]id'
d_dosuid = 
d_setresgid = define
d_setresuid = define
d_suidsafe = 
$
```

Or, slightly less obscurely now I've found the right name:

```
$ perl -MConfig -e 'print "d_suidsafe = $Config{d_suidsafe}\n"'
d_suidsafe = 
$
```

This shows that this Perl (a 5.12.1 that I built) does not regard SUID scripts as safe.

The real and effective user and group ID values are reportable with: RUID `$<`, EUID `$>`, RGID `$(` and EGID `$)`, or (more sensibly) using English:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use English '-no_match_vars';
print "EUID = $EUID; RUID = $UID; EGID = $EGID; RGID = $RGID\n";
```

Comment: `perl -V:'.*se*t*[ug]id.*'` /// `perl -V:d_suidsafe`